# How to pass a request in django urls

Tags: django, django-views, django-request

I have this url: (Django 2.0)

```
re_path('auth/(?P<code_>[a-zA-Z0-9]{12})/(?P<email_>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$', homePageView.autenticate, name='autenticate'),
```

in my **views.py**:

```
class homePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

def autenticate(self, email_, code_):
    try:
        user = Usuario.objects.get(email=email_,activated_code=code_)
        code = user.two_factors_auth_code
        if (not user.two_factors_auth) and (code == code_) and (len(code) == 12):
            user.next_login = True
        user.save()
        return redirect('home')
    except Usuario.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('home')
```

I wish I could login user in my autenticate method but I don't have a request parameter in my function.

¿How can I transform my autenticate function to this another?

```
class homePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

def autenticate(self, request, email_, code_):
    try:
        user = Usuario.objects.get(email=email_,activated_code=code_)
        code = user.two_factors_auth_code
        if (not user.two_factors_auth) and (code == code_) and (len(code) == 12):
            user.next_login = True
        user.save()
        ####################
        login(request,user)
        ####################
        return redirect('home')
    except Usuario.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('home')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use authenticate method in views like function based views.

in this method first argument is request. only rename first argument to request and its done

Comment: I tried that in the past and It did not works, but now, It works! thanks so much!